# How to store button click history time in SQL using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

im working with [Telegram.Bot](https://github.com/TelegramBots/Telegram.Bot) Libary using C#
i have an SQL Database i have a coulmn Called PostDate from Datetime Type
im trying to limit each user to use this if(true) 1 time per hour , lets say user clicked and the button called at 07/05/2018 17:45:00 and msgbox with "Hey" showed up and the user try call the hey again at 07/05/2018 18:41:00 i want message box to show up with the time left until user can call "hey" msgbox again if user try to call it again at 07/05/2018 18:45:00 the msgbox with "hey" will pop up again and inset to database the new datetime that the user can user the "hey" msgbox
the if condition that im talking about is down below.

ok 2nd try to explain im sorry for my bad english im ill do it the best i can

ok so i have a table called Accs and there is Username and Datetime Column called PostDate and in my code there is If statement this one i want to msgbox("Hey") can be called by user 1 time each hour , and write to PostDate where user like ecid the next time the msgbox can be called by user, and if user ask for msgbox("Hey") and hour didnt past then messagebox with the time left until he can call the next time to msgbox("Hey")

```
using (var GetLastPost = new SqlCommand("SELECT PostDate FROM Accs2 WHERE Username LIKE @user1", con))
{
    GetLastPost.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user1", ecid);
    con.Close();
    con.Open();
    using (var LastReader = await GetLastPost.ExecuteReaderAsync())
    {
        if (!LastReader.HasRows || !LastReader.Read())
        {

        }
        else
        {
            var DataTime = DateTime.Parse(LastReader["PostDate"].ToString());
            //   SqlDateTime sqlNow = new SqlDateTime(DataTime);
            SqlDateTime sqler = new SqlDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow);
            TimeSpan difference = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(DataTime);

            if (difference.TotalMinutes <= 60)
            {
                con.Close();
                con.Open();
                using (var PostCheck = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Accs2 set PostDate =  '" + sqler.Value + "' where Username like '%" + ecid + "%'", con))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Hey");
                    await PostCheck.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You can use Hey more " + sqler.ToString() + "Minutes");
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what currently happens? Also it would be benifical if you spaced out your code so its more readable

Comment: @Cacoon i think i explain what im trying to do better now lok at the edit

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are trying to limit each user to say "Hey" once per hour, correct?

Comment: @DioPhung Yeah sir thats what im trying to do

Answer (score 0):

3 things to note:

1. You need to know when was the last time user say "Hey",  `lastPost`= `SELECT TOP 1 PostDate FROM Accs2 WHERE Username = "abcd" ORDER by PostDate DESC`
2. If you want to allow the user to send 1 message per hour, then use

> ```
> if ((DateTime.UtcNow - lastPost).TotalMinutes >= 60) 
> {
>     // allow to say "Hey" 
> }
> else 
> {
>      // stop
> }
> ```

3. You can use SqlConnection more efficiently following [MSDN sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9197xfyw(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ```
> using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
> {
>     connection.Open();
>     // your code here 
> }
> ```

Comment: hey i tried this but the value is always true and let the user post any time and how many time he wants , after user say "hey" what string i need to  insert in my table PostDate column to lock this action to 1 time per hour i cant understand it so wierd

Comment: Every time the user is allowed to click on the "Hey" button, you need to store the current time. In MS SQL, use `SYSUTCDATETIME()` if you care about timezone, or simply `GETDATE()`. In C# it is `DateTime.UtcNow`.

If it's still not working, why don't you post your updated code here?